# modules and programs in Haskell - first steps

Tags: haskell, module

I am studying the example in section 3 on this page:

https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad

Basically, I would like to play with this example but I do not know how to make the code do anything. I take it that this is a "module", and that some modules are "programs" in Haskell, but I don't understand why this module has a function called "main" (I thought it would also have to be called "Main" to be a program, but I tried changing it and it failed to compile). If it is not a program, then what I am supposed to do with a module sitting all by itself? Am I supposed to import it into ghci and then type > main? If so, I tried but I can't make it happen.

Comment: You can open up GHCi and paste in `import Control.Monad.State.Lazy`. Then, you can try out the interactive stuff they talk about (like `runState (return 'X') 1`). One aside: this tutorial makes some simplifying remarks, so don't be surprised if you occasionally run into `StateT`...  Also, [this](https://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/haskell-importunimport-a-module-into-ghci/) covers imports and unimports.

Comment: The [Using GHCI section](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/ghci.html) in the GHC User's Guide might help.

Comment: Please consider asking a single question with the example code, filename(s), and commands ran.  As is your question is long and rambling, making it hard to answer in an objective fashion.

Comment: Thomas, I edited the question so less rambling, maybe it will help some future straggler like me.

Comment: EricR, Alec, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the sections titled "complete and concrete example" are complete and concrete examples. You can put the code in these into files with the same name as the module name (i.e. the StateGame module should go into a file called StateGame.hs).

You can then compile that with ghc `ghc StateGame.hs -main-is StateGame`. Alternatively you can rename that module to `Main`, then you don't need the `-main-is` part.